# spark cassandra metrics class not found

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to visualize some cassandra metrics on spark but it s doesn t work :(

My versions are :

- spark 2.0.2
- cassandra 3

I put on metrics.properties  :

```
executor.source.cassandra-connector.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.CassandraConnectorSource
driver.source.cassandra-connector.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.CassandraConnectorSource
```

but i have this error :

```
  ERROR org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem - Source class org.apache.spark.metrics.CassandraConnectorSource cannot be instantiated
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.metrics.CassandraConnectorSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSources$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSources$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSources(MetricsSystem.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.start(MetricsSystem.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createExecutorEnv(SparkEnv.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
```

Should i add something more in cassandra or spark ?
Could help me please?

Thanks by advance :)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am facing the same issue and getting this error in the executor logs.
I also observed that spark session is getting created before spark-app jar is copied to executor node.